# c++ segmentation fault when dereferencing a pointer to a vector of structures

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, hashtable

So I'm creating a closed-hashing hash table for a class and I have a structure

```
struct Example {
  string key;
  string data;

  Example() { key = "000"; }
};
```

and a class which contains a member that points to a vector of structures, a constructor, and a function I'll be using to illustrate the problem.

```
class hash_table {
  private:
  vector<Example>* hash;

  public:
  hash_table(int size);
  void dummy_method();
 };
```

It is meant to dynamically allocate the number of structures in the vector based on user/file input.

```
hash_table :: hash_table ( int size=10 )
{
  //initialize vector 
  vector<Example> * hash = new vector<Example>(size);
  //test objects
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    cout<<(*hash)[i].key<<endl;
}
```

the above code appears to initialize the 10 members, as it prints out "000" 
ten times.

however, once I try this by calling dummy_method-

```
void hash_table::dummy_method() { 
  cout<<(*hash)[0].key<<endl;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault

I'm pretty sure this isn't even the correct way to do this, but I've been looking/tinkering forever and I can't seem to find a solution.  I absolutely have to use a pointer to a vector of structures however, and I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to be dynamically allocating each of those structures as well (somehow).  Thanks for any help.

(also, yes, we actually HAVE to use namespace, thus no std anywhere)

Comment: You should store a vector, not a pointer to a vector. That will reduce the scope for bugs.

Comment: What's `htable` and how is it defined? Please post a full example code that reproduces the issue you're asking about. Otherwise it's hard to give useful answers.

Comment: sorry, htable is from the larger program. I copied the functions from the larger program to a smaller one in order to isolate the problem.  I edited it to reflect the correct code.  As of right now this is a completed program, so any problems should be isolated.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<Example> * hash = new vector<Example>(size);` expression will initialize a local variable with name `hash`, not a `hash_table::hash` member (which is left uninitialized).

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that.  Do you know if there an easy way to initialize the hash_table::hash member dynamically and populate it with dynamically allocated structs?  Sorry if that's a dumb question, my brain kinda melted from trying to figure this all out.

Comment: You just need to remove `vector<Example> * ` part or even rewrite it as `this->hash` to explicitly show that you are dealing with class member. Name clashes like this are quite troublesome in C++, you may want to use some naming convention to prevent this, like member variables start with `m_`, regular variables are always written in lower_case, functions are always written in CamelCase, type names start with `t_`, namespaces start with `n_`.

Comment: I knew I was going to feel incredibly stupid the moment someone answered and I wasn't wrong.  I really appreciate the help.